# Azure Devops build to create only bin,web.config and global.asax for webapi service

Tags: azure-devops

How to create a azure devops build definition only to publish bin,web.config and global.asax for webapi service.

Answer (score 0):

If you build a project in Azure DevOps, you'll get all the output. You're asking for a publish of the web API.

You're looking for an [Azure Web App deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=vsts&tabs=yaml).

> The simplest way to deploy to an Azure Web App is to use the **Azure App Service Deploy** task. This task is automatically added to the release pipeline when you select one of the prebuilt deployment templates for Azure App Service deployment. Templates exist for apps developed in various programming languages. If you can't find a template for your language, select the generic **Azure App Service Deployment** template.

Comment: when i download the publish artifacts am getting as a zip folder and to reach the bin i have to unzip and keep opeing many folder, how can i get it directly.

Comment: You don't need to unzip by yourself, azure app service deploy task will take care that for you. All you have to do is just include the task.